# CSS - Aligning text horizontal

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do two things on my webpage. One is I want to align two lines infront of each other with the gap like this. 
[image]

I want to maintain a gap between them. and second I want all my lines to be start on equal place. I mean you can see second line of second row that Singer has changed is position and stretch to back. Want to do like this

```
          Singer/songwriter/record producer
          Singer/songwriter/record producer/actor
          Singer/songwriter/record producer/actor
```

like this

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kp92Levd/)

### HTML

```
<div>
    <div class="float-left"> 
        AkonP .Diddy
    </div>
    <div class="float-right">
          Singer/songwriter/record producer
    </div>    
        <div class="float-left"> 
        Rick Ross
    </div>
    <div class="float-right">
          Singer/songwriter/record producer
    </div>    
        <div class="float-left"> 
     Michael Vick
    </div>
    <div class="float-right">
          Singer/songwriter/record producer
    </div>    
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.float-left{

    float:left;
    width:30%;
}
.float-right{

    float:left;
    width:70%;
}
```

Comment: The name `float-right` may be confusing to some, because it floats left. Maybe use `float-1` and `float-2` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of options

```
<table style="border:0;width:100%">
   <tr>
      <td style="width:30%;padding-right:20%;">
         Artist name
      </td>
      <td style="width:50%;">
         Singer/songwriter...
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Or

```
<div style="float:left; width:30%;padding-right:20%;">
   Artist name
</div>
<div style="float:left; width:50%;">
   Singer/songwriter...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have to use different elements. I presume you are doing (always post some code):

```
<li>
    <span style="float: left;">Akonp.Diddy</span>
    <span style="float:right">Singer/songwriter/record producer</span>
</li>
```

Try to add the first span a fixed `width`  to the first `<span>`, and `float` the second one to `left`. You may see as result the both elements floating to the same direction, but as the first has a fixed `width`, the second one will be pulled.

Comment: Yes exactly I was doing this.. I have  done as you suggested but now the second column has taken the place of 1st column. means they shifted. what I have done is <span style="width:30%">akon</span> <span style= "float:left">

Comment: Keep both floating to left, and define width only to the first one.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use   special character....I created a fiddle for you here `Data data`.http://jsfiddle.net/vashuStarPro/8mr66gjf/. It adds space to the letters.See fiddle

Answer (score 0):

My answer is using box-flex :)  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ocmuo182/2/)

```
<div id="p0">
<div id="p1">
    <ul>
        <li>AkonP.Diddy</li>
        <li>Rick ross</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="p2">
    <ul>
        <li>Singer/songwriter/record producer</li>
        <li>Singer/songwriter/record producer/actor</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
#p0 {
display:-moz-box;
display:-webkit-box;
display:box;
width:100%;
}
#p1 {
-moz-box-flex:1;
-webkit-box-flex:1;
box-flex:1;
}
#p2 {
-moz-box-flex:1;
-webkit-box-flex:1;
box-flex:1;
}
ul {
padding:0;
list-style:none;
margin:0;
}
```